# reset the file location using lseek() system call

Tags: c, system-calls, lseek

I tried to use the system call lseek() to get back the beginning of a file or reach the end of the file.

The exact code I used is:

```
int location = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET) //get back to the beginning
int location = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END) //reach to the end
```

However, after the file location has been reset, whenever I tried to use read(), the return value of read() is always set to -1, which means something was wrong. Furthermore, the errno message I got was Bad file descriptor. Does anyone know what should I do?

PS: I tried to close and reopen the file to help me get back to the beginning of the file and it worked. But I have no ideas on how should I get to the end of the file and read the entire file in the reverse order without using lseek().

Plus: a reproducible example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd;
    char buffer[1000];

    fd = creat("newFile", 0777);

    memset(buffer, 'a', 500);
    write(fd, buffer, 500); // fill up

    int location = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET); //get back to the beginning

    int read_bytes = read(fd, buffer, 500);
    // this should return the bytes it reads but it actually returns -1
    printf("%d\n", read_bytes);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show a full compilable example, the problem cannot be explained from those two lines of code

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe you should also check the return value of `lseek`

Comment: @Fred The reproducible example *must have a `main` function and no syntax errors*. That means a *complete program*.

Comment: the return value of lseek() seems good. It's the new file location as it should be.

Comment: @Fred OK, here's a minimal reproducible example for you. Next time, do it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `creat` function does not allow you to read from the file. It only allows you to write to it.

From `creat(2)`:

> `creat()`
>          A call to `creat()` is equivalent to calling `open()` with `flags` equal to `O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC`.

The important part here is `O_WRONLY`. That means "write only".

If you want to open the file (and create it) for reading and writing, then you can use `open` like so:

```
int fd = open("newFile", O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC, 0777);
```

The important part here is `O_RDWR`. That means "read and write".
If you want to have `open` give an error if the file already exists, add the `O_EXCL` flag; this causes `-1` to be returned and `errno` to be set to `EEXIST` if the file already exists when you try to create it.

Comment: So after I created a file and wrote something into it, I should use open() before I can use read()? But I thought the second parameter, which I specified to be 0777, already gives me the right to read, write and execute.

Comment: @Fred You can open it for reading and writing in the first place by using `open()` and the correct flags

Comment: @Fred Those are just the permissions on the file. You still have to `open` the file with the adequate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. properly declares the variable types
3. properly creates the file
4. properly includes the needed header files
5. properly checks for error indications from C library functions (and properly handles any error)

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd;
    char buffer[1000];

    // fd = creat("newFile", 0777);
    fd = open("newFile", O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC, 0777);
    if( fd < 0 )
    {
        perror( "open failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    memset(buffer, 'a', 500);
    write(fd, buffer, 500); // fill up

    off_t location = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET); //get back to the beginning

    printf( "%ld\n", location );

    ssize_t read_bytes = read(fd, buffer, 500);

    if( read_bytes < 0 )
    {
        perror( "read failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    // this should return the bytes it reads but it actually returns -1
    printf("%ld\n", read_bytes);

    return 0;
}
```

A run of the program results in:

```
0
500
```

Suggest reading/understanding the MAN pages for any C library functions your code uses

Comment: *BZZT* wrong: `__off_t location`. Just define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to an appropriate value and use `off_t`.

Comment: @JL2210,  Per the MAN page, the returned type from `lseek()` is `__off_t`  And the posted code runs with no warnings, errors

Comment: Then there's something wrong with that man page. `__off_t` is glibc-specific.

Comment: Here's the definition from the Linux man-page: `off_t lseek(int fd, off_t offset, int whence);`

Comment: Also, man is short for manual. There's no need to make it all caps.

Comment: @JL2210,  regarding MAN  That is just so it stands out in the comments     The command `manual` results in a message: `manual: command not found`

Comment: in the end, both `__off_t` and `off_t` cleanly compile, so it makes no difference

Comment: `__off_t` is not portable, so I suggest `off_t`.